# Get ActorRef to previously spawned EventSourcedBehavior

Tags: java, akka, akka-persistence

We are using event sourcing with Akka Persistence by extending EventSourcedBehavior. When we create the persistent actor we give it an unique name, by using an uuid (the same we use inside `create` to build the `PersistenceId`, for entity sharding):

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
String name = MyBehavior.nameFor(uuid);

ActorRef<Command> actorRef =
    context.spawn(MyBehavior.create(uuid), name);
```

Later on, when we want to send further commands to the actor, we would like to get an `ActorRef<Command>` from the context, since the `actorRef` object reference returned by `spawn` won't be in scope anymore. Think about commands as a result of subsequents HTTP requests.

We can't use `context.getChild(name)` as it returns `ActorRef<Void>`.

We've also considered actor discovery with Receptionist, but the documentation says it doesn't scale to any number of actors:

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/actor-discovery.html#receptionist-scalability

On the other hand, ActorSelection is not supported in typed, as per the following link:

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/from-classic.html#actorselection

We are not sure about the right approach here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it on the documentation. In a typed system, the correct way to handle persistent actors is by using `EntityRef` with `ClusterSharding`, as in the example linked below:
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/cluster-sharding.html#persistence-example

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to access the ActorRef of your previously spawned actor. Here is what I usually do.

```
private final Map<String, ActorRef<Command> instanceIdToActor = new HashMap<>();

private ActorRef<Command> getActorRef(String instanceId) {
  ActorRef<Command> instanceActor = instanceIdToActor.get(instanceId);
  if (instanceActor == null) {
    instanceActor = getContext().spawn(MyBehavior.create(), instanceId);
    instanceIdToActor.put(instanceId, instanceActor);
  }

  return instanceActor;
}
```

You must also remove the reference whenever the actor dies.

```
instanceIdToActor.remove(instanceId);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time answering, but that solution does not work in a cluster, as each node would have its own in-memory repository. It doesn't scale either as refs to persistent actors may grow up to tens of thousands